# source control with azure devops git repo in visual studio not in sync

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

We are using Azure DevOps Git repository and on the local machine we use Visual Studio to clone the repository with the version 2019. Of late more often than not when we try to sync-up the local repository with changes from Azure DevOps Git repo I see a mismatch and irrespective of doing sync repeatedly results in still not showing up latest changes from Azure DevOps Git repo onto the local. Sometimes even though trying to clone the entire repo also not works and now it's gotten to a point where neither the sync brings back latest changes nor clone. I'm unclear how to make this work and not having to sync repeatedly or clone the repo all the time which is time consuming and frustrating.

[image]

Comment: What are you looking at in the local and remote versions to confirm "still not showing up latest changes" ? (Is it possible you don't have the same branch checked out locally as what you're looking at on AzDO?)

Comment: @TTT, I look at the commit history to check and make sure Azure DevOps and my local repo are in sync.

Comment: OK. Is it possible either the pull or push is failing? Try it from the command line and see what happens. The command `git status` on your checked out branch will tell you how many commits ahead and behind the remote tracking branch you are. Then if you `git pull` followed by `git push`, and neither of them fails, then running `git status` again should show them in sync. If it still isn't synced, look at the tracking branch specified when you run `git status` and confirm it's the branch you think it is. If your local branch is tracking the wrong branch it could explain what you're witnessing.

Comment: Side Note, over time I have started to shy away from sync, and even pull by itself. Nowadays I tend to `git fetch`, inspect the remote branches, and then decide what to do myself. (Merge, rebase, etc.)

Comment: I see no pending items I tried `git` rebase and that's been hung for more than a day. I'll clone a new local repo and will try out `git pull` & then `git push` and see what I find when I do `git status`.

Comment: Oh- the rebase could be the problem (or another problem). If you run `git status` right now you'll see you're in the middle of a rebase. It's not actually hung, but it's paused, usually due to conflicts that you need to address before it can continue.